# How can I specify multiple ES module files output for Parcel?

Tags: typescript, parcel

I created simple project to take a look for Parcel. I want to create a library with multiple entry points, so I have this package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "parsel-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build --dist-dir dist './src/*'"
  },
  "targets": {
    "main": false
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/packager-ts": "^2.7.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-types": "^2.7.0",
    "parcel": "latest",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

TS config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": false,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

.parcelrc:

```
{
    "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
    "transformers": {
        "types:*.{ts,tsx}": ["@parcel/transformer-typescript-types"]
    }
}
```

I want to build a ts file like this:

```
export function add(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Old problem: Parcel produces an empty js file. What option I am missing or what option I am using wrong? Unfortunately, I couldn't find an example for TS library with multiple entry points which is using Parcel for bundling.
Solution for this: specify ES module or CommonJS paths.

UPD: I found out that I excluded CommonJS version build and didn't specify ES module path. So I have next problem: how can I specify multiple paths for ES modules?